# How to use groupBy() on relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Currently having trouble of using groupBy in nested relation on laravel. I have 3 Tables and I want to group the result base on the `CountryTbl` value. Here are the tables.

```
UserTbl
----------------------------------
id | name            | branch_id |
----------------------------------
 1 | Joseph          |     1     |
 2 | Manuel          |     1     |
 3 | Margaret        |     3     |
----------------------------------

BranchTbl
----------------------------------
id | branch_name    | country_id |
----------------------------------
 1 | Pampanga       |     1      |
 2 | Manila         |     1      |
 3 | California     |     2      |
----------------------------------

CountryTbl
------------------------
id | country_name      |
------------------------
 1 | Philippines       |
 2 | United States     |
------------------------
```

**This is my Model**

```
UserModel
public function branch()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Branch');
}


BranchModel
public function country()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Country');
}

CountryModel
```

Now, In the table shown above, I want to get all the users and group them by country.

Here is what I've tried.

```
public function getAllUsers(){
    $users = User::with('branch')
                   ->with(['branch.country' => function($q){
                       return $q->groupBy('country_name');
                   }])
                   ->get();
    return $users;
}
```

My code doesn't work. It always returns me an error saying:

> Syntax Error or Access Violation

Comment: I dont know what to call that way. but in some of my codes its working. Because it is nested relations.

Comment: branch table you don't have field `country_id` or `country_name` then how you doing eager loading by `branch.country`

Comment: Hi @KaranSadana, Thanks tho my bad. It should not be agency_id it must be country_id. Already edited the question :))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
User::with(['branch', 'branch.country' => function($q) {
        return $q->groupBy('CountryTbl.country_name');
    }])
```

or

```php
User::with(['branch', 'branch.country'])
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('branch.country.country_name');
```

Comment: Okey, ill try this.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below code

```
$data = DB::table('country')
    ->join('branch', 'country_id', '=', 'country.id')
    ->join('user', 'branch_id', '=', 'branch.id')
    ->select('country.country_name','user.name','branch.branch_name')
    ->groupBy('country.country_name')
    ->orderBy('country.country_name','ASC')
    ->get();
```